# How to use custom fonts in a property list file?

Tags: ios, plist

I use a third-party SDK in my iOS app which requires me to define the fonts I wish to use in a pre-defined .plist file. I have been using Lato-Regular all throughout the app but it seems I cannot use the same in a property list file for some reason. Is there any to achieve this?

P.S. I have checked and rechecked for the name of the font so that's not the problem.

Comment: Have you added your font to plist under the Font provided by application?

Comment: Installed first on your mac then add to xCode project navigator and then add to the plist

Comment: done that all too. as I said I use it with my code but not inside a .plist file

Comment: you have to do it inside .plist without it can't be used.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JhWIZ7LMVwU take a look at this video.

Comment: I have completed all these shahin. The fonts appear to be working fine too if I use them in the code. I just cannot seem to declare them in a .plist file so they can be used from there in the code

Comment: okay then i dont know about this.